# ASIFormDataRequest + WCF connot get responseData

Tags: ios, wcf, http, asihttprequest

My code is as follows:

```
-(void)testRMIS{
    NSString *loginString=@"http://192.168.1.109/Enjoy.ServicePortal/ServicePortal.svc/testOnly";
    NSURL *postUrl = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:loginString];
    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:postUrl];
    [request setResponseEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [request addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"application/json"];
    [request setUsername:@"Login"];
    [request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request startAsynchronous];
    [postUrl release];
}
```

When set a breakpoint in the wcf code I can't catch it.

But in the Objc code, I get this line:

```
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
```

but the `responseData` is `"Error request"`, which means HTTP 400.

Any help would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Try to browser to `http://192.168.1.109/Enjoy.ServicePortal/ServicePortal.svc` with a browser window. That might actually give you the answer.

Comment: I can get the ServicePortal Service page and which show the right page